# changing input value of one field when another is typed not working for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

i have a website where i have a form, the form has 3 fields which can be addedd multiple times on click, my code is like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $("#niy");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="client_type">Service Type</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_type" required name="service[]"></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="client_type">Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_type" required name="price[]"></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="client_type">Total</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" required name="total[]"></div></div>'); //add input box
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});



$('input[name="price[]"]').change(function() {
  $('input[name="total[]"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row container1">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label for="client_type">Service Type</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_type" required name="service[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label for="client_type">Price</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label for="client_type">Total</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_type" required name="total[]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="niy" class="btn btn-warning" style="color:white">Add New Service Field &nbsp;
      <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
    </a>
```

i want the total field to show the value from its respective price field, however here only first row does that, can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is because you only bind the `change` event which updates the value of the fields when the page first loads. This ignores all the fields which are added dynamically. To fix this use delegated event handlers - exactly as you are for the `.delete` button.

That being said, it's worth noting that there's several other issues which need to be addressed:

- Don't repeat the same `id` attribute value in the DOM. They need to be unique. Also, don't use `id` at all in content which can be repeated dynamically. Use `class` attributes instead.
- Don't use inline styling with the `style` attribute. It's bad practice to put one type of code in another, eg. CSS in your HTML, or HTML in your JS. In this case use an external stylesheet.
- Similarly, don't put HTML in your JS. Clone existing content instead of dumping a lot of HTML in the JS. In your original, if you changed the HTML template, then you'd need to also remember to update the JS file too. Using cloning avoids this problem.
- Don't double-wrap your jQuery objects. Eg. `add_button` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to use `$(add_button)`. It's worth prefixing variable names that hold jQuery objects with `$` for this reason.
- Don't use global variables where possible. They're bad practice for a variety of reasons, not least of which is that they lead to more length and harder to maintain code. A better approach in this case is to retrieve the number of elements already existing in the DOM and compare that to the known limit.

With all that said, here's a working demo:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var $container = $(".container");
  var $add_button = $("#niy");

  $add_button.on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.row').length >= max_fields) {
      alert('You Reached the limits');
      return;
    }

    let $newContent = $('.row:first').clone().appendTo($container);
    $newContent.find(':input').val('');
  });

  $container.on("click", ".delete", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.row').remove();
  })

  $container.on('change', '.price', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('.row').find('.total').val(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#niy {
  color: white;
}

#niy span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row:first-child .delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="client_type">Service Type</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control service" required name="service[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="client_type">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control price" required name="price[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="client_type">Total</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control total" required name="total[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="niy" class="btn btn-warning">
  Add New Service Field &nbsp;
  <span>+ </span>
</a>
```

Comment: actually i tried to impliment this in my form, and its throwing error

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: actually there is no container class in my form, and lot of row classes are ther, so some other row section is being added on button click and while clicking again it shows limit reached

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that :) I split the `.row` and `.container` classes to be separate elements to make the targeting of each `clone()` more simple.

Comment: yeah, i modified my code and made it in ur way, thanks

Comment: can you please tell me how to add a delete button to this

Comment: Sure, your JS was already in place to work, you just need to add the element with the `delete` class to the HTML. I updated the answer to include it. Note that I also set the CSS to not display the delete button in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet once, you will find runtime oninput updating totals. That imrpoves user experience.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".container1");
    var add_button = $("#niy");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields)
        {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="service_type'+x+'">Service Type</label><input type="text" class="form-control service_type" data-id="'+x+'" id="service_type'+x+'" required name="service[]"></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="price_type'+x+'">Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control price_type" data-id="'+x+'" id="price_type'+x+'" required name="price[]"></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="mb-4"><label for="total_type'+x+'">Total</label><input type="text" class="form-control" data-id="'+x+'" id="total_type'+x+'" readonly name="total[]"></div></div>'); 
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
});

$(document).on('input', '.service_type, .price_type', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(id > 0)
    {
        var service_type = parseFloat($('#service_type'+id).val()) || 0;
        var price_type = parseFloat($('#price_type'+id).val()) || 0;
        var total_type = service_type + price_type;
        $('#total_type'+id).val(total_type.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row container1">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <!-- Form -->
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="service_type1">Service Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control service_type" id="service_type1" data-id="1" required name="service[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <!-- Form -->
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="price_type1">Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control price_type" id="price_type1" data-id="1" required name="price[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <!-- Form -->
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="total_type1">Total</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_type1" data-id="1" readonly name="total[]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="niy" class="btn btn-warning">Add New Service Field &nbsp;
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
</a>
```